# Keeping a reference to deleted rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I'm working on a UITableview that has a set number of total rows, some of which get inserted and removed depending on user action.  I'm having trouble deciding on which way would be most efficient to implement this action. The two ideas I have had both work, but aren't very clean implementations.  They are:

1) add a boolean value to the data called (shownInTable) and set shownInTable to YES when inserted, NO when removed.

The issue I have with this method is that when the tableView asks for a section row count or a cell, i have to iterate through the array, checking which data is currently shown.

2) Create 2 arrays, one containing all data as a reference, one mutable containing only the data shown.  Give data from the mutable array to the table.  Use the reference array to grab data to be inserted into the mutable array, then delete from the mutable array as necessary.

The problem I have with this is that it requires a long setup process, creating both arrays. I.E. if there are 10 possible rows of data... the 10 objects are created and placed into the reference array, and 5 are duplicated and placed into the mutable array.

Is there a better way to keep track of this data as it moves in and out of the table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place the same object in two arrays, the objects are not duplicated, they are simply referenced twice.
So, the second is the correct way in most cases.

If the goal of your filter is a search, for example, you can create the first array, and then the second using a filter with predicate to speed up the creation process.

For example, you have an array of objects (in this example: array of activities) and want to show only the activities that contains "programming"

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(activityName CONTAINS[cd] %@)", @"programming"];  // activityName is the @property that you want to apply the filter to
NSMutableArray *arrayToShow = [[firstArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```